# Find 3rd highest sum of a pair in an array

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

If we have to find 3rd highest sum of a pair of elements in an array.

E.g. Given

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

then, we have these pairs:

```
(1,2) = 3, (1,3) = 4, (1,4) = 5, (2,3) = 5, (2,4) = 6, (3,4) = 7
```

Here, the answer is 5 and the pairs are (1,4) and (2,3).

The array is not necessarily sorted and duplicated values in the array can appear in pairs.

I have tried an algorithm with two nested loops.  Time complexity is quadratic.  How can I lower the complexity?

Now, if we need to find the kth highest pair sum. Can we go for minheap or maxheap wherein we first store the pair sums in the maxheap/minheap and then find the kth largest of them.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: So what you have tried so far??

Comment: I could think of just the brute force approach i.e to compute all the possible pairs sum and then find the third highest of them.

Comment: First step: sort the array if it isn't already.

Comment: The question is to find the pair with the 3rd largest sum.

Comment: @Vikram can (4,4) be counted as a pair or pair should be unique?
By unique, what if the array is something like `{1,2,3,4,4}`. In this would you count (4,4) as a pair?

Comment: @Vikram Is the source array sorted?

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish - each element is to be considered once. If {1,2,3,4,4} is the array then (4,4) can be counted as a pair.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow- The source array is not necessarily sorted.

Comment: @Vikram Write the program in C++!:) It can be easy done using std::multimap.:)

Comment: @Vikram In any case you need some additional container. You could use a sorted list of lists of pairs.:)

Comment: @Vlad: the question is only tagged `c`.

Comment: @vikram In as sorted array without duplication "arr[n-1]+arr[n-2] " always yields the 3rd highest sum. So 1. Sort, 2. Remove Duplicates and get the result.

Comment: @k4vin - What if I need to find the kth largest pair sum?

Comment: @k4vin: your assertion fails if there are duplicates in the array.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `minheap` and `maxheap`, but this looks like a quadratic complexity at least.

Comment: @chqrlie but you can always easily remove duplicates from a sorted array in linear time.

Comment: @Vikram - "arr[n+k-2]+arr[n+k-1]" will do that

Comment: @k4vin: That is not the point, if there are duplicates in the array, `arr[n-1]+arr[n-2]` is not necessarily the 3rd largest sum.  If you remove all duplicates, you also remove the pairs with identical elements, if you don'y, you count those multiple times.  You need a more accurate algorithm.  Furthermore, a full sort is not needed and increases the complexity.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes I am wrong. I didn't consider that omitting duplicate pairs could affect the end result.

Answer (score 0):

First try a brute for approach:

- scan the array with a double loop to find the largest sum `sum1`;
- rescan the array with a double loop to find the largest sum `sum2` different from `sum1`;
- rescan the array a third time to find the largest sum `sum3` different from both `sum1` and `sum2`;
- rescan the array one final time to print all pairs that have sum `sum3`.

Time complexity is quadratic, but it will handle duplicates correctly.

You can then drastically reduce the complexity by filtering the array, only keeping the largest 3 numbers with at most 2 instances if there are duplicates.  This can be done in linear time.  You then run the quadratic algorithm on a set of at most 6 elements.  Total complexity is still linear.

Comment: This is what I have tried. I thought if there was a way to improve the complexity.

Comment: @Vikram: you should rephrase the question and include what you've tried, what problems you face.  Quadratic complexity is not a problem if the set is relatively small.  For large sets, you can cut the complexity by skipping numbers below a threshhold in the outer loop.  Only the largest numbers are involved in the largest sums.  Sorting the array would make this easier, but should not be necessary.

Comment: What if I need to find the kth largest pair sum?Then how should I go about?

Comment: You can run `k` rescan loops looking for the largest sum strictly less than the one found in the previous iteration.  If you use the filtering, you can keep the `k+1` largest elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=[30,4,2,5,6,0,9];
var first=a[0];
var second="";
var third="";
// Solve it in O(n) time
for(var i=1;i<a.length;i++)
{
    //Find first Max
    if(a[i]>first)
    { 
      second=first;
      first=a[i];
    } 
    //Find second Max
    else if(a[i]>second && a[i]!=first )
     {
         third=second;
         second=a[i];
     }
    //Find third Max
    else if(a[i]>third && a[i]!=first && a[i]!=second)
         third=a[i];
}
console.log(first+second+third);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int thirdHighest()
{
    int sum = 0;
    List<int> number = new List<int>();
    int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 };

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
        {
            sum = array[i] + array[j];
            if (number.Contains(sum))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                number.Add(sum);
            }
        }
    }

    int[] array1 = new int[number.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < number.Count; i++)
    {
        array1[i] = number[i];
    }

    Array.Sort<int>(array1);
    Array.Reverse(array1);

    return array1[2];
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged [c], not [c++] nor [java].

Answer (score -2):

you can use it this way:

```
int varmax1, varmax2, varmax3, varmax4, varmax5, varmax6, i, j, max=0, max2=0, max3=0;
for(i=0; i<3;i++)
{
    for(j=i;j<3;j++)
    {
        sum=arr[i]+arr[j];
        if(sum>max)
        {
            max3=max2;
            max2=max;
            max=sum;
            varmax1 = varmax3;
            varmax2 = varmax4;
            varmax3 = varmax5;
            varmax4 = varmax6;
            varmax5 = i;
            varmax6 = j;
        }
        else if(sum>max2)
        {
            max3=max2;
            max2=sum;
            varmax1 = varmax3;
            varmax2 = varmax4;
            varmax3=i
            varmax4=j

        }
        else if(sum>max3)
        {
            max3=sum;
            varmax1 = arr[i];
            varmax2 = arr[j];
        }
    }
}
printf("elements with 3rd largest sum are %d %d", varmax1, varmax2);
```

Comment: how are you sure that var1 and var2 are the correct pair. What if in the last iteration the `sum > max2`, then the value of max3 will be correct but `var1+var2 != max3` hence incorrect answer.

Comment: This does not work if multiple pairs have sum `max` or `max2`

Comment: yeah. thats correct. For that we just have to save those elements at some other place and display all those elements at last.

Comment: Well that would leave a very dirty code to handle, don't you think so?

Answer (score -3):

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    int[] intList = {5,4,7,8,12,16,19,5};



    Set<Integer> intSumList = new HashSet<Integer>();
    List<Integer> intSumList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<intList.length;i++){

        for(int j=(intList.length - 1);j>i;j--)
            {
            //  System.out.println(intList[j]+" --- "+intList[i]);
                intSumList.add((intList[j]+intList[i]));
            }   
        }

    for(int ele : intSumList){
        intSumList1.add(ele);
    }

    Collections.sort(intSumList1);

    for(int ele : intSumList1){
        System.out.println(ele);
    }


    System.out.println("sum is "+intSumList1.get((intSumList1.size()-3)));
    }
```

Comment: um... the question is tagged `C`

Comment: also, just posting a bunch of code is most likely not going to help the OP